# How can I inject repository from Nest.js?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm, query-builder

I'm working with NestJS and TypeORM. When trying to call the get user api but, I'm getting the following error: TypeError: this.userRepository.findByIsMember is not a function
From what I see, this error occurs because the corresponding repository could not be injected.
I'd appreciate your help.

user.repository.ts

```
import { Repository, EntityRepository } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from 'src/entities/user.entity';

@EntityRepository(User)
export class UserRepository extends Repository<User> {
    //problem function
findByIsMember(isMember: boolean): Promise<User[] | undefined> {
    return this.createQueryBuilder('user')
        .select([
            'user.name AS name', 
            'user.gender AS gender', 
            'user.phone_number AS phoneNumber',
            'user_category.category_id AS category',
            'user.email AS email'
        ])
        .leftJoin('user_category', 'user_category.user_id = user.user_id')
        .where('is_member = :isMember', { isMember })
        .getMany()
}
}
```

user.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { User } from 'src/entities/user.entity';
import { UserRepository } from './user.repository';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private readonly userRepository: UserRepository,
) {}

async findByIsMember(ismember): Promise<User[]> {
    return await this.userRepository.findByIsMember(ismember);
}
}
```

user.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { AdminModule } from 'src/admin/admin.module';
import { AdminRepository } from 'src/admin/admin.repository';
import { AdminService } from 'src/admin/admin.service';
import { Admin } from 'src/entities/admin.entity';
import { User } from 'src/entities/user.entity';
import { TokenModule } from 'src/token/token.module';
import { TokenService } from 'src/token/token.service';
import { UserController } from './user.controller';
import { UserRepository } from './user.repository';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([
      UserRepository,
      User,
      Admin
    ]),
    TokenModule,
    AdminModule
  ],
  providers: [UserService, TokenService, AdminService],
  exports: [UserService],
  controllers: [UserController]
})
export class UserModule {}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule, TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { DatabaseTypes } from '../database/database.enum';
import { DatabaseFactory } from '../database/database.factory';
import { AdminModule } from 'src/admin/admin.module';
import { UserModule } from 'src/user/user.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(
      DatabaseFactory.createDatabase(DatabaseTypes.MYSQL).options(),
    ),
    AdminModule,
    UserModule
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

database.factory.ts

```
import { DatabaseTypes } from './database.enum';
import { Database } from './database.model';
import { MySQL } from './mysql.model';

export class DatabaseFactory {
  static createDatabase(type: DatabaseTypes): Database {
    switch (type) {
      case DatabaseTypes.MYSQL:
        return new MySQL();

      default:
        throw new Error('Database Type이 지정되지 않았습니다.');
    }
  }
}
```

mysql.model.ts

```
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { MYSQL } from '../config/dotenv';
import entities from '../entities';
import { Database } from './database.model';

export class MySQL extends Database {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  protected composeOptions(): TypeOrmModuleOptions {
    const {
      HOST,
      PORT,
      USERNAME,
      PASSWORD,
      DATABASE,
      SYNC,
      TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS
    } = MYSQL;

    return {
      type: 'mysql',
      host: HOST,
      port: PORT,
      username: USERNAME,
      password: PASSWORD,
      database: DATABASE,
      synchronize: SYNC,
      entities: [
        ...entities,
      ],
      migrations: [TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS]
    }
  }
}
```

ERROR

```
[Nest] 1664  - 2022. 10. 14. 오전 9:43:32   ERROR 
[ExceptionsHandler] this.userRepository.findByIsMember is not a function
TypeError: this.userRepository.findByIsMember is not a function
at UserService.findByIsMember (/Users/iwonje/mcn-admin-backend/src/user/user.service.ts:13:42)
at UserController.findOne (/Users/iwonje/mcn-admin-backend/src/user/user.controller.ts:28:47)
at /Users/iwonje/mcn-admin-backend/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:38:29
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at /Users/iwonje/mcn-admin-backend/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:46:28
at /Users/iwonje/mcn-admin-backend/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-proxy.js:9:17
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `@InjectRepository(UserRepository)` instead of `@InjectRepository(User)`. This way, you get the custom repository rather than the standard

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but the problem still hasn't been solved.
[Nest] 2823  - 2022. 10. 14. 오후 1:35:33   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] this.userRepository.findByIsMember is not a function
TypeError: this.userRepository.findByIsMember is not a function
    at UserService.findByIsMember (/Users/iwonje/mcn-admin-backend/src/user/user.service.ts:14:42)
    at UserController.findOne (/Users/iwonje/mcn-admin-backend/src/user/user.controller.ts:28:47)
    at /Users/iwonje/mcn-admin-

Comment: That should have done it. Got code to reproduce the problem in a git repo?

Comment: How can you solve what?